# ASP.NET - i'm looking for a way to change a subString font into a gridview cell

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="searchDescription" runat="server" Height="26px" Width="270px"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <br />

        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Търси" onclick="Button2_Click" />
        <br />
        <br />
```

So here is my gridview :

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Center" AllowPaging="True" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4"
            ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Марка" HeaderText="Марка" SortExpression="Марка" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Година" HeaderText="Година" 
                    SortExpression="Година" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Мощност" HeaderText="Мощност" 
                    SortExpression="Мощност" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Вносител" HeaderText="Вносител" 
                    SortExpression="Вносител" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" 
                    SortExpression="Description" />
            </Columns>
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

I have a description text field and DropDownList and a button which generates a query that takes out from the DB * from the table where one of the column is equal to the selected Item from the DropDown and if in the description cell contains the subString from the description text field. So i want when the description cell appears into the gridView, the subString from the text field to be bolded.

Here is my button method:

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string srchDescription = searchDescription.Text;
        string slctItem = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString();

        con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmdForDescription = new SqlCommand("SELECT Description FROM car_table WHERE Вносител = '" + slctItem + "'", con);
        string descriptionText = cmdForDescription.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        bool containsDescription = descriptionText.Contains(srchDescription);

        if (containsDescription)
        {

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM car_table WHERE Вносител = '" + slctItem + "'", con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            GridView2.DataSource = ds;
            GridView2.DataBind();
            con.Close();
            Label2.Visible = true;

        }
    }
```

Comment: WHich one is description field?

Comment: Soryy it's on my language...  The last one is the description one - >

<asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" 
                        SortExpression="Description" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First set `htmlencode="false"` on your bound field like this.

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" 
                 htmlencode="false"   SortExpression="Description" />
```

The in [RowDataBound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx) of your gridview write following.

```
if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
   string textToReplace = searchDescription.Text;
   string newText = "<b>" +searchDescription.Text + "</b>";
   e.Row.Cells[4].Text =e.Row.Cells[4].Text.Replace(textToReplace, newText);    
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! :)

Comment: Happy to help you :)